# how to open a database in sqlplus which is already created

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

In SQL*plus i can't open the databse which is already created in my computer....

the error it shows that "the database is not yet open"
and i want to know that in what command is suitable to open database.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're getting an error such as `ORA-01219: database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only`.  In that case, the fix is to connect as `SYS` and execute `ALTER DATABASE OPEN`:

```
C:\Users\Luke>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sun Mar 17 10:31:40 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

SQL> select count(*) from user_tables;
select count(*) from user_tables
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01219: database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only


SQL> alter database open;

Database altered.

SQL> select count(*) from user_tables;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       935
```

If you get an error `ORA-01507: database not mounted` when you run `ALTER DATABASE OPEN`, run `ALTER DATABASE MOUNT` before `ALTER DATABASE OPEN`.

There might a reason why the database isn't open and/or mounted.  Perhaps it failed to open?  In that case, `ALTER DATABASE OPEN` is likely to result in an error other than `ORA-01507`.  If so, the folks on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ should be able to help you.